# SPARKLINE function with LOWCOLOR and YMIN doesn't get along very well

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-sparkline

I am using the `SPARKLINE` function to display a bars graphic within a cell, using the optional parameters `lowcolor` and `ymin`. The idea behind `lowcolor` is to be able to identify the lowest value with a specific color, for instance for the formula

```
=SPARKLINE(QUERY(GoogleFinance("FB", "price", TODAY()-60, TODAY(), "daily"), "SELECT Col2"), {"charttype","column";"color", "#4147BF"; "highcolor","green";"lowcolor","red"})
```

I would get

[image]

Which isn't exactly very useful for me, as the lowest value is hardly visible.

So I added the `ymin` optional parameter to the above formula (in the example I just simplified it with a hardcoded value, but in my real sheet is calculated)

```
=SPARKLINE(QUERY(GoogleFinance("FB", "price", TODAY()-60, TODAY(), "daily"), "SELECT Col2"), {"charttype","column";"color", "#4147BF"; "highcolor","green";"lowcolor","red"; "ymin", 100})
```

Whichs gives me:

[image]

And that part is working OK, the min value of the Y axis is now set to 100, instead of the minimum value in the dataset. The problem is that the lowest bar in the dataset is not colored. I understand that Google Sheets is mixing up the min value of the dataset with that of the Y axis.

Would there be any way to be able to color the minimum bar of the dataset and still be able to set the `ymin` parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that is realy possible, but what about a result like this?
[image: sparkline]

the cell below has the same sparkline formula but with `"charttype", "winloss"`

Comment: That's clever, it achieves the goal of identifying the lowest value at a glance. with the drawback of having to use a second row, but I might end up implementing this.